# Trying to call google translator api from Javascript code, getting 403 error

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-403

I want to build a simple website in Javascript which when loaded, prints "hello" in Chinese language.

For this,I was trying to use google translator call, like below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- bootstrap.min.css + some js related files -->

<body onload="myFunction()">
</body>
    </head>
    
    <script>
    
        function myFunction()
        {
            //alert("hello");

            var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var API;
        API = 'https://translate.google.co.in/?sl=auto&tl=zh-CN&text=hello&op=translate';   
        
        //alert(API);
        ourRequest.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                         {
alert(ourRequest.responseText);                     
                        }
            };
        ourRequest.open('GET', API,false);
        ourRequest.send();
            
            
        }
    
    </script>  
    
    
</html>
```

When I try to run this, I get the below error :

try.html:43 GET https://translate.google.co.in/?sl=auto&tl=zh-CN&text=hello&op=translate 403

Seems google server rejected my call .
Can someone please help me to fix this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, modern browsers do not allow access across domains. See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

This means that both the web page where the request is made and the web page it tries to load, must be located on the same server.

You'll have to use [Google's Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).